# Gateway Server error on standalone Spark cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I recently installed Apache Spark 1.2.1 (the binary with hadoop24) onto a Windows XP (sp3) machine in standalone mode after purchasing "Learning Spark". When I started the pyspark shell, I encountered the following output:

```
C:\spark\spark-1.2.1-bin-hadoop2.4\bin>pyspark.cmd
Running python with PYTHONPATH=C:\spark\spark-1.2.1-bin-hadoop2.4\bin\..\python\
lib\py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip;C:\spark\spark-1.2.1-bin-hadoop2.4\bin\..\python;
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
find: version: No such file or directory
else was unexpected at this time.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\spark\spark-1.2.1-bin-hadoop2.4\bin\..\python\pyspark\shell.py", line
 45, in <module>
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PySparkShell", pyFiles=add_files)
  File "C:\spark\spark-1.2.1-bin-hadoop2.4\python\pyspark\context.py", line 102,
 in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway)
  File "C:\spark\spark-1.2.1-bin-hadoop2.4\python\pyspark\context.py", line 212,
 in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway()
  File "C:\spark\spark-1.2.1-bin-hadoop2.4\python\pyspark\java_gateway.py", line
 73, in launch_gateway
    raise Exception(error_msg)
Exception: Launching GatewayServer failed with exit code 255!
Warning: Expected GatewayServer to output a port, but found no output.
```

The shell appears to start, i.e., the chevon prompt (>>>) is displayed, but the above output concerns me and I would like to resolve it. Any helpful feedback would be appreciated. Thanks.